# How do I allow a user to search and view 2 columns found in the library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

As an example I have an Order library with a column called Account, Month, and Email Subject line.  When the user uses a search via the site Search box it is typically the account number they search on and then the user is then forced to review thru each individual result to determine if the library document is associated with the month and email subject line they need...

My hope was once they searched on the account number there would be 2 other filters available for the Month and Subject line.  Is this possible...

Note we can not do Term or Term stores..Hoping there was a relatively easy OOB/webpart solution..

Note the library can not do a filter since we are close to 5,000.  The library has views by Month.  The Month column is indexed.  This allows us to keep under a < 5,000 view, but this forces the user to go into 12 views to search for Historical info..

Comment: Search refiners (filters) would be available if your order library had a content type, and all documents within the library had that content type assigned.

Comment: So if I assigned them all a content type of orders then i am good